# モジュールがシンボルなしでビルドされました。

Tags: c#, wpf

エラーの原因が分かりません。
エラー内容は以下の通りです。
「mscorlib.resources.dll' が読み込まれました。モジュールがシンボルなしでビルドされました。」
おそらく無限ループさせている処理の部分が原因だと予想して今調査しているのですが、ソース自体に問題はないと思います。

これは何が原因で起こるエラーなのでしょうか？
初歩的でしたら申し訳ありませんがご教授をお願いします。

Comment: それは本当に"エラー"ですか？ビルドに失敗したり、プログラムが停止したりしていますか？

Comment: 返答から、エラーではないということが確認出来ました。
現在は正常に動作しております。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

それはVisual Studioの用語で「モジュールの読み込み通知」と呼ばれるものです。文字通りモジュールが読み込まれたときに発生する正常なログ出力でエラーメッセージではありません。

真のエラーを探すには「デバッグ」→「例外」メニューのダイアログで「Common Language Runtime Exceptions」にチェックを入れて実行するとよいです。

Comment: 細かい説明ありがとうございます。
解決することが出来ました。

Answer (score 2):

表示されているのは出力ウィンドウだと思いますが、そこを右クリックすると「モジュールの読み込みメッセージ」にチェックが付いていることがわかると思います。これがpgrhoさんの説明の「モジュールの読み込み通知」です。もちろんチェックを外せば表示されません。

名前の通り、エラーでも警告でもなくメッセージです。

Comment: チェックを外すと表示されなくなりました。
ありがとうございます